# how to add a parameter into header, I call webservice by axis2

Tags: web-services, soap, header, apache-axis

> I use Axis2 RPCServiceClient to call a webservice. and all calls to the service must include 3 parameters: UserName, Password and reqID. reqID is a GUID parameter generated by me.
>
> The reqID is required to put into header.
>
> When I use soapUI to test the service, by the Http Analyzer, I could find the reqID is include in the request headers with SOAPAction, Content-type, User-Agent and Authorization.

how to add reqID into header?

```
   `RPCServiceClient client = new RPCServiceClient(); 
    Options option = client.getOptions();
    option.setAction("http://localhost:8080/api/Getbooks");  
    EndpointReference erf = new EndpointReference(serviceAddress); 
    option.setTo(erf);    
             
    HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
    auth.setUsername("test");
    auth.setPassword("test");
    auth.setPreemptiveAuthentication(true);
    
    option.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);'
    
    [![this is request headers][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Create an instance of org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient
>
> Create an instance of org.apache.axis2.client.Options
>
> create a http client header

```
Header header = new Header();
    header.setName("Request-Id");
    header.setValue(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(header);
```

> options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS, list);